# Error in getting data from xml using AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I am using AJAX for reading data from external xml file but it is giving error "Invalid argument"
I am using IE 8

PFB the code:

```
var xhr;
 xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**xhr.open("GET","C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Project/POC/ajax/Data.xml", false);**

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
 { 
 if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200)
 {  
 var items = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('name'); 
 var output = '<ul>'; 
 for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
 output += '<li>' + items[i].firstChild.nodeValue + '</li>'; 
 output += '</ul>';  
 var div = document.getElementById('update');
 div.innerHTML = output;
 }
 }
 xhr.send();
```

The line in bold is giving error.
Any idea ?
thanks in advance

Comment: XMLHttpRequest does not support file:// protocol

Comment: Thanks all for this solution.. I was unaware of this.May be i need to find some other solution to access local file from AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `url` not `path`, like change :

```
xhr.open("GET","C:/Users/abc/Desktop/Project/POC/ajax/Data.xml", false);
```

to, something like

```
xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/your_Project/POC/ajax/Data.xml", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests will not work for file based urls you need to host your sources on a server to make XMLHttpRequest calls

Answer (score 0):

You are creating request to the server for `GET` for xml. but GET only understands HTTP requests so it is throwing error.

To resolve this problem you should add the xml file to the solution or web deploy directory and then make request with browser address and if successful then make it with your xhr object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put xml file on a web server, and point your xhr target to that file url. 
which looks like this:

```
xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/yourpath/Data.xml", false);
```

The basic html file, which contains your js code, should also be put on the web server too.

```
http://localhost/yourpath/basic.html
```

Because of the Same Origin Policy, you can not send a ajax request from file system to web server url, but can send the request from server A to server B, and the two servers should on same origin, both are

```
http://localhost
```

etc.